# How to add new item into the main menu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

1. Create a new controller called User. Create the following pages for
   it: index, register, login and logout. It's just enough to use a
   generator script to acomplish this.
2. Add new items into the main menu: Register and Login. The main menu
   is defined in the application layout file
   app\views\layouts\application.html.erb. Notice that we are not yet
   adding a menu link to the index page at this stage.
3. Try out your application. If the new pages don't work, restart
   Mongrel web application.

what is the second point? How should i do it?

Comment: Please reword your question and explain what you've done, what you're trying to achieve, and what you've having difficulty with. I also recommend providing some code to support your question so we have something to work with.

Comment: I saw an example in (http://rails.francik.name/tutorial/chapter/5) and  as said in that example i created a controller User and as u can see the second point, add new items into main menu. I do not know how i can do it.

Comment: You need to provide more detail. I suggest rewording your question and including some of your code relevant to the part of the tutorial you're getting stuck on. It's nearly impossible to interpret your question without further information/a better description at this point.

Comment: Your edit just made the question worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jarek Francik was my teacher at Kingston University...

I did this tutorial a few years ago. The second step is to add the links for the new actions you have generated: `index, register, login and logout`

Go to your application.html.erb and edit it:

```
  ...
  <div id="nav">
    <%= link_to_unless_current "Home",  :controller => "site", 
                                        :action => "index" %> | 
    <%= link_to_unless_current "About", :controller => "site", 
                                        :action => "about" %> | 
    <%= link_to_unless_current "Help",  :controller => "site", 
                                        :action => "help" %> |

    #include the new actions as the example below:
    <%= link_to_unless_current "Login", :controller => "user", 
                                        :action => "login" %> | 

 </div>
```

Also note that this tutorial is for Rails 2.3.9. I suggest you to take a look on his video about rails 3 and shopping cart: http://ecommerce2011.tumblr.com/post/11687504985/lecture-4-techniques-part-2-the-shop-on-rails

Answer (score 0):

In [chapter 3 of the tutorial you're completing](http://rails.francik.name/tutorial/chapter/4), section 9 (Finishing touches), you created a navigation menu in the following snippet:

```
<div id="nav">
  <%= link_to_unless_current "Home",  :controller => "site", 
                                      :action => "index" %> | 
  <%= link_to_unless_current "About", :controller => "site", 
                                      :action => "about" %> | 
  <%= link_to_unless_current "Help",  :controller => "site", 
                                      :action => "help" %>
</div>
```

To add the new items into the menu, you need to create two more `link_to_unless_current` calls in the nav div. For example, the changed code might look something like this:

```
<div id="nav">
  <%= link_to_unless_current "Home",     :controller => "site", 
                                         :action => "index" %> | 
  <%= link_to_unless_current "About",    :controller => "site", 
                                         :action => "about" %> | 
  <%= link_to_unless_current "Help",     :controller => "site", 
                                         :action => "help" %> |
  <%= link_to_unless_current "Register", :controller => "user", 
                                         :action => "register" %> |
  <%= link_to_unless_current "Login",    :controller => "user", 
                                         :action => "login" %>
</div>
```

I suggest going back through chapter 3 and checking that you understand what's happening.